# Imported Image looks weird

Tags: color-management

My problem is that when I import an image in blender the colors are weird. They don't look the same compared to the original image. If anyone has a solution please tell me.

Original Image
[image]

Blender Image
[image]

Answer (score 1):

The problem is probably in color management. Go to the render tab, and look for color management. It is probably on filmic at the moment. Change it to standard, and the colors will be right.

Comment: As @Relevred said, change the _Color Management_ from _Filmic_ to _Standard_ (I see in the screenshot it's set to Filmic). The image also looks a bit semi-transparent in your Screenshot. Maybe this is another reason for the different look.

Comment: I went into the render tab but I couldn't find the color management. I just saw render image, render animation and other things. Could you maybe be a little more specific

Comment: Nvm, I found it and I changed it to standard, but it still didn't work.

Comment: Try going into rendered mode rather than material preview.

Comment: I don't get wat you mean. Could you explain in a simpler way.

Comment: press ''Z' and go select rendered mode.

Comment: It works now. Thank You So Much